# Pandas/Dataframe: How to assign default value when condition fails while taking single cell value from data frame using python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let consider the below code:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=["A", "B"])

x=0

print(df)

x=df.loc[df['A'] == 3, 'B', ''].iloc[0]
print(x)
```

while printing the x I get 4 as the output.Its fine. If the condition get fails as per the below code

```
x=df.loc[df['A'] == 33, 'B', ''].iloc[0]
```

I want to print the x's initial value 0 and I want avoid the below error:

> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Guide me to avoid the error and display the initial value of x. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `next` with default parameter for get value if no match condition:

Notice - Also there is another error - need only value `B`, remove `''` (maybe typo)

```
default=0
x = next(iter(df.loc[df['A'] == 30, 'B']), default)
print (x)
0
```

Answer (score 2):

you can have a look at try and except for exception handling,
Use:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=["A", "B"])

x=0

print(df)

try:
    x=df.loc[df['A'] == 3, 'B', ''].iloc[0]
    print(x)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
2  5  6
3  7  8

Too many indexers #the exception

0 #the initial value
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable response. Your code gives me the default value. Thanks..